# Firebase authentication (Google sign-in) does not work when emulating on different PC

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm developing my app on OS X and everything works great. I then connect my git repository to Android Studio on my PC, pull down my project and start my app. Now I can't sign in, getting an error that goes like: `Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}` (from running `getStatus()` on my `GoogleSignInResult`). What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have the SHA-1 of your debug key on your Windows machine added to your project.  You probably added the one generated on your OSX machine but forgot to do it on the new one.